# Can't Connect to an RDS from my home computer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to connect to an RDS from my home computer.

This is an established database, I'm migrating it to a new system.

I can not connect to it from my home computer.

I have set the security to Public Accessibility.

I've set VPC the Security rules to allows in bound connections.

What do I do next to debug it

RDS Screen
[image]
Security Groups
[image]
VPC
[image]

---

I've included information on the Subnet is that relevant?

[image]
[image]

Comment: use this: https://aws.amazon.com/en/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/ (how about outbound (connections)?)

Comment: What's a public subnet?

Comment: Did you try a search for *public subnet* on Google? That question seems to be something you could research yourself nearly as fast as you could post that comment, and you wouldn't still be waiting for an answer.

Comment: I did and I got an incredible amount of information unrelated to my problem.

Comment: how do access the database? I assume `blackedout.us-east-1.rds.amazon.com` what is IP of this URL when you try from home? What about from the office? if it comes back as 172.30. something, then the database is simply not accessible from the internet. You gave incredible amount of information unrelated to your problem. Start with some tutorial that teaches you how to set up and connect to the database; and most questions will have obvious answers. After that post questions on ServerFault, rather than on SO.

Comment: To connect to a private database from your home, you need a VPN connection to the VPC or a bastion host to use as a tunnel. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/

Comment: @Felix The url of blackedout.us-east-1.rds.amazon.com is 52.205.***.*** so I think it's accessible to the public, and that's when I perform a nslookup against the URL.

I can get it working when I make a new database. I need to access the one that is already running unfortunately, which I did not set up.

Comment: @jordanm I gave up on that and just made it public for now.